# Complicated logic of group by and partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table as per the script below.
The data that I want finally is shown in the screenshot.
The logic that is to be implemented is :
If SUM(FPR_QTY) > QPA, Use QPA without summing it up.
Else, use FPR_QTY.

Eg explanation: For the first 4 rows, TOT_FPR > QPA, so I just need 1.
While for rest 4 rows, TOT_FPR < QPA, i need to use TOT_FPR.
So, ultimately, I want 21 against each record.

Please let me know if my explanation is not clear.

```
    create table #TEMP
(QPA int
,FPR_QTY int
, key1 varchar(2)
, key2 varchar(10)
)

insert into #TEMP values
(1,1,'K1','kk1')
,(1,0,'k1','kk1')
,(1,1,'k1','kk1')
,(1,0,'k1','kk1')
,(50,5,'k2','kk1')
,(50,5,'k2','kk1')
,(50,5,'k2','kk1')
,(50,5,'k2','kk1')

select *
,SUM(FPR_QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY key1) AS TOT_FPR
from #TEMP
```

[image]

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to post some of the details here. What is TOT_FPR? And what is FINAL?

Comment: @SeanLange TOT_FPR I am calculating the Total fpr qty(See my last select which has partition by clause).Final is what I want the output to be(derived column with the logic).

Comment: OK I see TOT_FPR but FINAL makes no sense to me. Where does 21 come from? I can't find any logical way to come up with that.

Comment: Where does the 21 come from? should it be 20?

Comment: For first 4 records, because the key1 is same and QPA for each record is less than TOT_FPR, I just want to add 1 once. For rest 4 records, because the key1 is same and TOT_FPR<QPA, I want the TOT_FPR for all those 4 records. Now, because the entire dataset key2 is same, my desired output is 20 + 1 against each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...I was able to write the query within two selects. I wish I could accept my own answer as it is most simplest and will run without failure.

```
select * ,SUM(IIF(TOT_FPR>QPA,IIF(QPA_IND = 1,QPA,0),FPR_QTY)) OVER (PARTITION BY key2) FINAL
from
(
select *
,SUM(FPR_QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY key1) AS TOT_FPR
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key1 order by QPA) AS QPA_IND
from #TEMP
)T
```